# Laravel GroupBy fails in scheduled command

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to send a daily email with the outstanding items to be collected.

I have an items table which has the following:

```
id   |   group_id   |   quantity   |   collected   |   person_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   32efsd3    |   2          |   0           |   1  
2    |   32efsd3    |   2          |   0           |   1
3    |   12sdf4d    |   1          |   0           |   1
4    |   544dsfd    |   1          |   0           |   2
```

A person can have many items that are uncollected and the collections are grouped by the group_id column.

I'm running a query as follows:

```
$items = \App\Item::where('person_id',1)->where('collected',0)->get()->groupBy('group_id');
```

This works when outputting via the browser but when I try to do this as a scheduled command it fails with the error.

> BadMethodCallException  : Method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getKey does not exist.

Can anyone tell me why this fails as a scheduled command but not when called via a route / controller?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `groupBy` before `get()` ?

Comment: If I do that I get errors asking me to group everything else such as the ID etc

Comment: What does this return: `$items = \App\Item::where('person_id',1)->where('collected',0)->groupBy('group_id')->toBase();`

Comment: When running via the command I get PDOException  : You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances #

Comment: I've solved by putting the query into the mail view rather than the command/mail instance. It just seems an odd way of doing it.